# How to append(both prefix and suffix) a string

Tags: shell

I have a file called b.txt with following content

```
libiomp5.so
libmkl_avx.so
libmkl_core.so
libmkl_def.so
libmkl_gf_ilp64.so
libmkl_gf_lp64.so
libmkl_gnu_thread.so
```

I want to prefix following string

```
cp /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib/
```

and suffix following string

```
/home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs
```

In the end, it must look like this

```
cp /home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs/libiomp5.so /home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs
```

I tried the following, but errors out

```
ls | grep *.so | sed 's/.*/cp /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib/&/home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs'
```

I need to append(prefix/suffix) irrespective of matching string in a file?

Comment: You are talking about these strings as if they were just any text strings, but they are in fact commands and pathnames, are they not? Are you later going to execute these commands? If so, is there a reason why you do not want to copy the files mentioned in your text file _without creating the command line for doing that as a text string first_?

Comment: As it stands, this is a duplicate of "[How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/39800)", but I don't think that the solutions there would help you as I _believe_ you actually want to copy files, not transform text.

Comment: Do you just need to do this? `cd /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib  && cp -t  /home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs *.so`

Comment: Glenn, seems your command will copy all *.so files. but it looks cool though if i need to copy all files in one single command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk -i inplace '{print "cp /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib/"$1,"/home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs"}' input
```

---

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print "cp /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib/"$1,"/home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs"}' input > output

mv output input
```

---

However I think this is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  It seems like your goal is to copy these files and there are certainly better ways to do it.

Comment: I tried the following the following, but it errors out..

`gawk -i inplace '{print "cp /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib/"$1,"/home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs"}' b.txt`

Comment: What is the error?  Do you have `gawk`?

Comment: I got the following error using gawk
`[oracle@dhft0oqr601 enterpriseR]$ gawk -i inplace '{print "cp /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/lib/"$1,"/home/oracle/staging/enterpriseR/old_libs"}' b.txt
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:  GNU long options:`

Comment: What do you get from `gawk --version`?  You may need to redirect your output to a temp file.

Comment: `GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.`

Comment: @user918753: Ah, yeah I think the inplace option was added in gawk v4.1